# How do i unpack tuple with different number of elements without using splat operator?

Tags: python, list, function, parameters, arguments

It is a part of my university project, and I am trying to make a function that returns multiple variables (unpacked tuple) to call another function with a proper number of arguments.

```
value = function_list[i](*func())
```

This was easy just using *(splat) operator until one of our instructors told us not to use this operator. Then, I tried to unpack tuple by assigning it into variables manually.

```
a, b = func()
function_list[i](a, b) #Causes error when a function requires more/less than 2 arguments.
```

Function_list is a list of multiple function definitions that may have a different number of parameters. So this is a problem in some cases. Those functions are not made by myself therefore I can't change those parameters to be optional.

Is there any finest way to replace * operator to get my all functions working properly?

Also, I am not allowed to use these keywords:

```
as, assert, asynch, await, break, class, continue, except, finally, global, is, lambda, nonlocal, raise, try, with, yield.
```

Comment: Are there multiple `func`s? One for each function in `function_list`? And you can assume that the amount returned by `func` will always be correct for the corresponding function?

Comment: Is this some kind of code challenge? I can think of a way to do this without `*` but it wouldn't be pretty or efficient. There's a reason `*` exists...

Comment: @Seb Teachers have dumb requirements. I can see it being helpful  in some cases, but they took the restrictions too far here imo.

Comment: Your splat solution has the same limitations as manual unpacking. The splat way isn't immune to a mismatch in the number of pieces of data returned by `func`. If the splat solution worked, so will the second way.

Comment: One option would be to assemble the call together as a string and feed it to exec or eval.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a weird requirement not to be able to use `*`, but here's what I've come up with:

```py
import inspect, functools

def get_min_max_arg_count(func):
    params = inspect.signature(func).parameters
    defaults = [p.default for p in params.values()]
    return defaults.count(inspect._empty), len(params)

def call_with_params(func, params):
    for param in params:
        func = functools.partial(func, param)
    return func()

def call_matching_func(func, function_list):
    '''Call `func` and the first function in `function_list` that
       has a signature matching the tuple returned by `func`.'''
    params = func()
    n_params = len(params)
    for fn in function_list:
        n_req, n_max = get_min_max_arg_count(fn)
        if n_req <= n_params <= n_max:
            return call_with_params(fn, params)
```

Note that `call_matching_func` assumes that any `func` you'll pass in returns an iterable.

Note also that I've decided that keyword arguments do not exist.